# Salesforce CLI not respecting versions in package dependencies

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package

We've got **App2** package which depends on **App1@0.1.0.LATEST**. However, CLI doesn't seem to respect versions in package dependencies. For instance, it's NOT preventing **App1@2.0.0.NEXT** package version from being installed. I expected some error message instead.

Is it correct?

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        ...
        {
            "path": "app2",
            "package": "App2",
            "versionName": "Version 1.0",
            "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT",
            "default": false,
            "dependencies": [
                {
                    "package": "App1",
                    "versionNumber": "0.1.0.LATEST" // <-- exact version expected
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "app1",
            "package": "App1",
            "versionName": "Version 2.0",
            "versionNumber": "2.0.0.NEXT", // <-- not the expected one, no errors though 
            "default": false
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Salesforce CLI is not that formal. It **does allow** version inconsistency in package dependencies once the package could pass 'Verifying dependencies' checks. In other words, 2.0.0.NEXT version should have **backward compatibility** against 0.1.0.LATEST